# Objective-C: regex to match {{ and }} and [[ and ]]

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have strings containing occurrences of [[ and ]] and {{ and }} . Which regex would work in the following code so that single occurrences of [ ] { } stay intact?

```
NSString* initialString = @"[[hi]] {{this}} {is} [a] {{string}}";
NSString* regex = @""; // Which regex would work
NSString* finalString = [match stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regex withString:@""];
```

Expected output:

hi this {is} [a] string

Comment: you want to remove the [[]]{{}} all these charecters from string?

Comment: sorry ... updated the post ... I want all {..} and [..] intact, while all [[..]] and {{..}} to be stripped off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the most obvious thing would be:

```
@"\\{\\{|\\}\\}|\\[\\[|\\]\\]"
```

Which literally just specifies to match `{{` or `}}` or `[[` or `]]`, the various slashes sneaking in because {, }, [ and ] are all parts of the grammar that normally specifies a regular expression and because slashes themselves need to be escaped in string literals.

So e.g.

```
NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression
        regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\{\\{|\\}\\}|\\[\\[|\\]\\]"
        options:0
        error:nil];

NSString *initialString = @"[[hi]] {{this}} {is} [a] {{string}}";
NSString *finalString =
    [expression 
        stringByReplacingMatchesInString:initialString
        options:0
        range:NSMakeRange(0, [initialString length])
        withTemplate:@""];

NSLog(@"final string: %@", finalString);
```

Outputs:

```
2013-05-09 00:15:57.699 Untitled[1064:707] final string: hi this {is} [a] string
```

Comment: You can use Objective-C++ with C++11's "raw string" feature to get rid of the double backslashes: `pattern = @R"(\{\{|\}\}|\[\[|\]\])"`.

Answer (score 0):

try like this may be it'l helps you.

```
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"[[]]{{}}"];// declare set of unwanted charecters here.
NSString* initialString = @"[[hi]] {{this}} {is} [a] {{string}}";

initialString = [[initialString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
```

O/P:-

```
 hi this is a string
```